# Unable to click on the button in chrome even though id or the locators of the web element or unique and visible on the page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

For this page, `https://dev.simplify360.com/`, login button with `"id=rp"`, was clickable in chrome using selenium 2.53.1 and 3.

But running it now, getting the exception `"element not clickable"`.

Not able to understand why this is not visible. I can achieve this using keys.return on mac. As this is not the standard way, trying to figure out what went wrong when it was working.

Chrome version: 54.0.2840.98 (64-bit)

Button code:

```
<div>

<input class="submit btn btn-block btn-primary" value="Login" id="rp" style="margin-top: 12px; margin-right: 17px; margin-bottom: 7px;" type="submit">

</div>
```

Exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (888, 456). Other element would receive the click: <div class="row">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426935 (820a95b0b81d33e42712f9198c215f703412e1a1),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 33 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'nagarjunaMBP.local', ip: '172.16.1.3', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.1', java.version: '1.7.0_71'
Session ID: 550d02f66708962a5eebcd76e4440774
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{platform=MAC, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={userDataDir=/var/folders/g4/dylg4g7s7wbdtg_f6mtzj8m00000gn/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.YxbtCE, chromedriverVersion=2.25.426935 (820a95b0b81d33e42712f9198c215f703412e1a1)}, networkConnectionEnabled=false, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, version=54.0.2840.98, pageLoadStrategy=normal, takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, hasTouchScreen=false, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]
```

Comment: So what have changed since the moment it was working for you?

Comment: don't see anything changed

Comment: You wrote: "*was clickable in chrome using selenium 2.53.1 and 3*". When did it stop being clickable?

Comment: yesterday morning it was clickable, but nothing has changed. can you have a look at the page and try on chrome.

Comment: Please post the full exception message and add a tag for the language you want the answer in.

Comment: @JeffC posted the exception and the tag

Comment: I looked at the page. When I ran it, I got a message that the DIV for the three links under the Login button would get the click. The problem seems to be that Chrome is either miscalculating the size of the Login button or the other DIV is overlapping it. You can either use Actions and `.moveToElement()` with an offset or you can use the JSE way. Note that using JSE is not a user scenario. Users can't click buttons using Javascript so you will want to be careful about it's usage.

Comment: @JeffC, can you try using the `//*[@id='rp']` or `driver.findElement(By.id("rp")).click();` Both used to work on chrome. Not sure if this is an issue with specific version of chrome.

Comment: I tried the second... I'm getting the same issue. I'm guessing that the layout of the page changed.

Comment: @JeffC even if the page layout has changed. `id` is there which is unique in the page. Wondering why this issue is being thrown by chrome in an simple login screen

Comment: I explained why... it's because another element is overlapping it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WebElement btn = driver.findElement(By.id("rp"));
btn.submit();
```

Try using `submit()` instead of `click()` as the type of the element is submit, not button.

```
<input type="submit" ... >
```

The code is working fine for me on Chrome.

Comment: this works, any idea why click is not working on chrome

Comment: I think it's due to the type="submit", I have seen same kind of issue previously as well. If you observe the HTML code, the login fields are not inside any <form> tag and type='submit' elements are for submitting a form. If you go little up you will see a ::before element. Basically I think dev team is using some widget for the login form and it's getting created after the DOM is ready. And if you look at the error "Other element would receive the click: <div class="row">...</div>" this div is actually the parent of the login form.

Comment: I think the click() is not able to click on the element because it's NOT a individual elements but actually a widget. That's why the parent of the widget is receiving the click. In other hand submit() can be performed on any element inside a form and it'll submit the complete form. That is why submit() is working and not click(). I might be wrong but that's what I feel the issue is all about :)

Comment: I am not able to figure out why his code was working well earlier and the same code not working now?

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy are you sure no changes has happened from the dev side? I think element type=submit has been changed though id & all is still same and may be that's why chick() is not working properly now.

Answer (score 2):

This issue comes only when working with chrome driver as the chrome browsers uses point location. When the element position is not fixed and we are trying to do some action on that particular element will result an error as 'selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException - Element is not clickable at point (xx, xx).

Try the below code.

```
driver.get("https://dev.simplify360.com/");
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("rp"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,"+ele.getLocation().x+")");
ele.click();
```

For more detail on this issue read the documentation [here](http://learn-automation.com/how-to-solve-element-is-not-clickable-at-pointxy-in-selenium/)

Comment: Though the above code works which is one of the different ways of handling the scenario, trying to understand why identifying using the id getting failed all of a sudden.

Comment: You might have tried your code on browser other than Chrome earlier, that's why it worked earlier. Such issue happens only with Chrome

Comment: no, I was working on chrome earlier as firefox not able to pick the base URL. So was using chrome

Comment: Inspect login button and refresh the URL again, you will notice disabled="disabled" set for login button at the end, so the element you are trying to click is getting disabled, earlier this might not have been set, so your code works earlier, now and you need above solution for the fix. This is what I am getting html <input id="rp" class="submit btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit" style="margin-top: 12px; margin-right: 17px; margin-bottom: 7px;" value="Login" disabled="disabled">